# In C#. What is the differences between String and string?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

In C# there are two string types. (The same for booleans, object, ect.). One that begins with uppercase and one lowercase. String and string. They seem to have the same methods.

So whats is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is a keyword, while `System.String` is a class. You can consider `string` to be an alias for `System.String`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference... you can't use String without `using System;` beforehand.

[What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)