# What's the difference between string and String in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

What's the difference between string and String in C#? Both seem to refer to the .NET data type System.String. Is the former a C#-specific data type which maps to the .NET type System.String and String is just short hand for System.String?

StyleCop is telling me that I should be using "string" over "String" but I kind of like having all my data types appear in the same color and case.