# Comparing two string

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'm having two string.

1. string
2. StriNG

Compare these two string and the result should be TRUE (ie,) both the string are same.

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: Convert both strings to uppercase

Comment: I suppose this will guide you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: Sometimes it is also useful doing something like this: http://bit.ly/JsSdmO

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? What effort did you put into solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET strings are case-sensitive, so `"string"` is different from `"String"`, or whatever. If you want to ignore lowercase and uppercase differences use:

```
string.Compare(strA, strB, true);
```

This will return an int (-1, 0, 1). If you want a boolean instead just use:

```
string.Equals(strA, strB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

Anyway it results a bit difficult to understand what you are asking in this question. I hope I have guessed what you wanted to know.