# pros and cons of using the struct or class for string

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

I have two scenarios where both a Struct and Class are acceptable, and I'm wondering what is the best practice.

Scenario 1:

```
public static String foo(){...}//String is a class

public static string foo(){...}//string is a struct
```

Scenario 2:

```
public foo(String bar){...}//String is a class

public foo(string bar){...}//string is a struct
```

What are the pros/cons to each implementation?

Comment: `string` is not a struct. It's an alias for the class `System.String`.

Comment: `string` is a C# alias for `System.String` which is a class. It is not a struct.

Comment: Actually, there is a significant difference for the compiler (not very significant, but significant nonetheless).  If you use the upper-case `String`, the compiler has to resolve it in the context of your `using` statements, to see whether you indeed meant `System.String` or perhaps `AdvancedPhysics.String` or `RememberToBuyButter.TieAroundFinger.String`.  Lower-case `string`, on the other hand, is a keyword, and can only ever refer to `System.String`.

Answer (score 5):

The implementations are the same. `String` is a class, `string` is just alias.

For details see the following answer:
[What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: phoog's comment makes this technically incorrect, but unless the OP is using a theoretical physics library it's extremely unlikely for String to be anything other than System.String, so it's correct in the most likely case.

Comment: @KeithS nor for that matter, is it that likely that someone who could code a worthwhile theoretical physics library not spotting the downside of naming any .NET class `String`, at some point before they shipped.

Comment: Who knows, those string theorists are a loopy bunch (or so CBS tells me :P ). I seem to remember an episode where our heroes are trying to build a smartphone app, and have to kick Sheldon out of the development effort (mostly for being such a micromanager/ivory-tower type, but still).

Answer (score 1):

`String` and `string` are the same thing. They're both reference types, which means they are classes (little 's' `string` is an alias to the real class `String`).

I personally prefer using the class names instead of the aliases in my code.  I guess I prefer the consistency between declaring variables of a certain type and then using static methods off those types (like `String.Format`).

Comment: Thanks @Cicada - guess I typed that too fast.  It made sense to me.  :)

Comment: What's static methods got to do with anything? You could argue just as well for `string.Format` than for `String.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

string is just an alias of String Type, the code MSIL is same

Answer (score 0):

String and string is same such as Int32 and int.