# string alias works without System.String But String does not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I faced a strange confusion today. Although I read the difference between String and string in C# in this post : [What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string). But when I try to use `String` with capital letter without using the namespace `System`, it was not recognized. Like

This code works,

```
using System;

String s = "";
```

But without using `System`, it gives error.

Whereas `string` with small letter works with and without using the `System` namespace.

If String and string are same things then why one works only with its namespace and other works with and without namespace as well.

Comment: have you ensured that **Using System;** namespace is included in your class file? as you can see in the provided link *string is an alias for System.String*, so its behave as expected.

Comment: when Using System is included then String and string both works. but When it is not included then only string with small letter works. If both are the same then why one works and other does not?

Comment: Usman, if you read that [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string) the first line in accepted answer is "string is an alias for System.String". Its mean if you write small letter **string** it will be same as **System.String**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` is a C# construct that *translates*, during compilation to `System.String`.

Every C# program default has:

```
using string = System.String;
using char = System.Char;
using int = System.Int32;
using double = System.Double;
```

`System.String` is the class. You can't use the type `String` without having access to the `System` namespace (so, either fully qualified as `System.String`, or with a `using System;` directive).

Answer (score 1):

`String` is an alias for `System.String`.  See the answer with 728 score on the SO answer you linked to for a list of some of the aliases.  If you use the alias, it automatically grabs the `System.` bit, so you don't need to explicitly reference it, coz it already is.

Answer (score 1):

System.String is a class of System namespace.
string reference directly to it.

When you type string, you access to all methods (and constructors, etc) of System.String.

The same thing with `Nullable<T>` :
You can write, example

```
int? myInt = 2;
```

It's the same thing of

```
Nullable<int> myInt = 2;
```

Only Alias utility

Answer (score 1):

Well think of this as below

Lets say we have a Namespace Foo that has a Class called Boo. Now If we need to call Boo we need to include that in the project using "Using" keyword.

In case we create an alias(Not sure whether it is possible or not) for ex : Foo.Boo > NewBoo

in that case the compiler will see that as Foo.Boo

Here in String case.

When we write **string** that is compiled as System.String hence we do not need to do any sort of inclusion of the System Namespace to access string.

But in case of Just String we need to include it.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually true, this won't compile without `using System;` There was a squiggle in the line `String name = "me";`

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name1 = "me";

        String name2 = "me";
    }

}
```

When I put mouse on `string` it says `class System.String` and when I put it on `String` it says `the type or namespace String could not be found`