# Aliases and dot net types and c# types

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, resharper

When I use resharper tool, it just says "use built-in type "string" rather than using "String". Similarly, it converts UInt32 to just uint.

I have googled this and all I can find is they are aliases. Aliases meaning "Duplicates". Ok.
But, what exactly do they mean about it ?

1. When both are same, why the tool suggests using "string" and "uint" for "String" and "UInt32" ?
2. Also, what is the difference between dot-net types and C# types.

Have googled it but couldnt find any satisfying answers.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between String and string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer given by Rafal sums it up, but there are a couple of clarifications I'd like to make: the only case when using keywords rather than type names is necessary is when defining an enum's underlying type -- In that case, using the latter would not be allowed.

Example:

```
enum Foo : Int32
{
}
```

The above won't compile.

Also, while I generally prefer to use keywords, it must be said that while the types are the same for every language running on the .NET Framework, the keywords are different. For example, while in C# `long` is an alias for `Int64`, in C++/CLI, `long` is actually an `Int32`. That can create some confusion when, for instance, porting code between CLI languages.

Comment: Thanks Eve.. couple of things I never heard of.. but, can u clarify  me what is the difference between dot-net types and C# types with an example ?.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. There is *no* difference, as Rafal rightfully pointed out. The compiler directly maps the keywords used in C# to the types contained in the FCL (or, if you prefer, "dot-net types"). C#, as a language, does not have any primitive type which is not defined in the framework common to all the other ones.

Comment: Thanks Eve..
+1 for "The compiler directly maps the keywords used in C# to the types contained in dot net types"

Answer (score 1):

- `String` and `string` are same and so are the `UInt32` and `uint`.

This just due to CLS-compliance, so that you could write C# class library and use in VB program and vice versa.

Some excerpts from MSDN:

> To fully interact with other objects regardless of the language they were implemented in, objects must expose to callers only those features that are common to all the languages they must interoperate with. For this reason, the Common Language Specification (CLS), which is a set of basic language features needed by many applications, has been defined. The CLS rules define a subset of the Common Type System; that is, all the rules that apply to the common type system apply to the CLS, except where stricter rules are defined in the CLS. The CLS helps enhance and ensure language interoperability by defining a set of features that developers can rely on to be available in a wide variety of languages.

Please refer [Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Harsh. If I understand it correctly,"string" is useful even when using in a VB programming, but "String" is not ? (Since is it specific to C#) ?

Comment: `String`, `Int32`, `UInt32` are very generic & can be written in both C# and VB programs, and reverse is not always true (i.e. it is language specific). :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `String` and `string` because as you have pointed out those are aliases - alias is just a different name for the same thing.

As to why Resharper does something you should ask or seek on resharper dedicated site. In my opinion it is merely question of convention - you should use one of those and why not use the one that majority uses.

Comment: Thanks Rafal.. but could you please tell me about the second question ?