# Difference between String and string in Android

Tags: android, string

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between `String` and `string` in Android?

Comment: Do you mean `java.lang.String` and `R.string`?

Comment: what is the question? and upvotes?

Comment: If you are talking about String class then refer this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: please ask with the exact package names, else we are just guessing what you mean

Comment: you should give (and look at it, and, while you're at it, read the doc related to it) the fully qualified name (with package and everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string refers to string(sub class) inside R class in your Project.

String refers to java.lang.String package

Answer (score 6):

String is a class  which is present in library java.lang.String, whereas string is an xml file

present in values  in android where you will refer id with values in which you will retrieve

in coding.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are asking about [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [android.R.string](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html).

`String` class is defined in package `java.lang`  which is automatically imported to your android project (infact all java project).

string is `android.R.string`, which is static string's given in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these links

[String Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

[string Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html)

For Example look at the code below

```
String name = "";
  switch (row.getNameKey()) {
  case keyName1:
    name = getString(R.string.keyName1);
    break;
  case keyName2:
    name = ...
    ...
}
```

R.string is used to getString from Resources (Strings.xml)...