# c#: String class vs string struct

Tags: c#, string, class, struct, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

I have been some time working with C# and i have ever noticed any diference between both types.

```
String myStringAsClass;
string myStringAsStruct;
```

Is there any diference other than the clarification you may use on the code or convetion to use the static functions from String class and declarations from string struct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Duplicate question, and incorrect premise. `string` is *not* a struct - it's just an alias for `System.String`.

Comment: The **only** difference between those is that `String` will require a `using System;` directive, where-as `string` is explicitly `global::System.String`, so doesn't need any directives.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7074/1236044

Comment: Well, thanks for the clarification, my own confussion then, since i was searching using struct on the keywords i didnt found the correct answer, my apoligizes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same. They are both reference types.

```
System.String == string
System.Object == object
System.Int32 == int
System.Int64 == long
```

...etc.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is an alias to `System.String`, just as `int` is an alias to `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

There IS a difference between a class and a struct in C#. However that is **irrelevant** here since

`String == string`  and both are  `class`

So, to summarize, there is NO difference between the two, and `string` is a class.