# How to turn off alias auto corrects in the IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For some reason my pinky finger likes to keep the shift key down a bit longer than I normally like.  So I end up typing `STring.Empty` quite a bit.  Visual studio *helpfully* converts that to `string.Empty` which is not the desired behavior.  I would much rather it be converted to `String.Empty`.  Notice the differences in capitalization.

I am quite aware that `string` is [simply an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string) for `String`; so this boils down to a simple personal preference on how things are color coded in the IDE.

Is there a way I can tell visual studio to always auto correct to `String` instead of to the alias?  This could save me an untold number of times pressing the back button on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE will only "auto-correct" to types is knows are valid in the current scope.  `string` is always valid, but `String` is only valid if you've referenced the `System` namespace with a `using` directive.  If you did reference `System` then VS 2012 will "auto-correct" to `String`, not `string`--which has been my experience.

Comment: System is referenced at the top, but `string` is still defaulted.