# String and string

Tags: c#, string

What is the difference between `String` and `string` in c#?

Even if I use `String` in place of `string` and assign a variable it does the same functionally as `string`. Then what is difference between them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7077/155407

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: `string` is `struct` but `String` is a `class`