# Redundant type conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

In a code example:

```
int age;
...
age = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

I see no point to put `(int)` before conversion. Can I safely remove it to:

```
age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

There are the same cases, such as:

```
height = (double)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the cast and running the code?

Comment: What's the problem you had when you removed it?

Comment: For int32 there is no problem but for int64 there is error `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) `

Comment: That's because an `int64` (a `long`) does not fit into an int (your variable age).

Comment: Seem they can be safely removed if the output variables are defined correctly.

Comment: If you have a tool like `ReSharper`, it'll even flag it as "Type cast is redundant". It's simply cluttering the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast here is a no-op, as [`ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `int` anyway and [`int` and `Int32` are the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care).

So yes, you can and should remove the cast there. My guess is that the original author of the code just did not know C# very well.

If you're converting an `Int64` that's really a [`long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152868/c-sharp-accepted-style-for-long-vs-int64) so you should assign it to a `long` and not an integer. If all you care is being able to use it as a number and you're not returning it - I recommend just assigning it to a `var` and letting type inference take care of it for you.