# How to Pick up values from datagrid ,search the database and update new values?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a datagrid and in it I have many rows. I just want to pick up 2 columns from which one row from which one column will search the database for that row with that value and the second column will update that row with the new value. Please help.

My code which is giving a syntax error

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'*

my code

```
{
            using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=PersonalDetails;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                con.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    String insertData = "UPDATE  Test SET AvailableQty = " + "VALUES (@Qty) Where ItemCode = " + "VALUES (@ItemCode) ";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value ?? DBNull.Value);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's probably rejecting the second VALUES in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong update query change your query like

```
String insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = @Qty Where ItemCode = @ItemCode";
```

For more information [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

For Getting the `availableQty` from `database` use select query like

```
Select availableQty from tablename where `use here primary value column and it's value'
```

like i have `id` as a primary column with value `1` then i write

```
Select availableQty from tablename where id = 1
```

After getting value you can easily substract like

```
double substractval = availableQty  - dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
```

Now at last use your `update` query like

```
Update tablename set availableQty = '"+substractval +"' where "pass primary column and value
```

You have to use this type of scenario.
Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: i want i want the availableqty to subtract the qty from it and update database ...

Comment: you want to substract available qty from which quantity.plz explain .i will tell that how to update but plz explain deep and more,it's not clear.thanks

Comment: i want to the  availableQty from the database to subtract the qty from the datagrid and update it in the datbase field availableqty

Comment: i tried this but it dident work  String insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = (AvailableQty - @Qty) Where ItemCode = @ItemCode";

Comment: brother no one can give you whole code it's a wrong thing,just understand my logic it's easy.Already I have given you all code just check the logic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of codes are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

I think you misunderstand the syntax of [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) in `T-SQL`.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=PersonalDetails;Integrated Security=True"))
{
       con.Open();
       for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
       {
            string insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = @Qty Where ItemCode = @ItemCode";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value ?? DBNull.Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
}
```

Comment: Thankx Bro ... could u correct this also (String insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = (AvailableQty - @Qty) Where ItemCode = @ItemCode";)

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is wrong, that's why it's giving to you a syntax error:

```
string insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = @Qty WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode";
```

And please try to avoid using the `String` class: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077/1141063).

Comment: Thankx Bro ... could u correct this also (String insertData = "UPDATE Test SET AvailableQty = (AvailableQty - @Qty) Where ItemCode = @ItemCode";)