# XNA Textbox loop

Tags: c#, textbox, xna

So im trying to make a textbox ( well not exactly a textbox, just changing a spriteFont text ) on XNA 4.0 win game heres my code so far :

```
usernameVar.Draw(spriteBatch, newInputText);
```

That will draw newInputText string each frame

```
newInputText = username.update(mouse);
```

That will set the string but heres my problem

```
class Textbox
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle rectangle;
    public bool isClicked;

    public Textbox(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRectangle)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        rectangle = newRectangle;
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
    }
    public String update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
        var textboxText = new newText();

        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {
            isClicked = true;
            if (isClicked)
            {
                textboxText.newtext = "a";
                Connection.sendPacketBool("ae", textboxText.newtext);
                return textboxText.newtext;  
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
class newText
{
    public String newtext
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.newtext; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.newtext = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

This textbox.cs file is giving me some errors first what should I do to avoid returning something outside the IF statement ?

```
public String update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
        var textboxText = new newText();

        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {
            isClicked = true;
            if (isClicked)
            {
                textboxText.newtext = "a";
                Connection.sendPacketBool("ae", "a");
                return "yo";  
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Since that return null breaks me textbox ( i cant add null text to the spritefont )
Also If I remove the return null adding return "something" I get this error on the set propertie

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
```

Sorry for this, im very new to C# and all this stuff, thanks

Comment: Stack overflows occur when you have an infinite loop or recursion.

Comment: How do you use the `Update()` method? The problem does not seem to be within the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact structure of your project, and I'm not sure the reason for the `newText` class, but the property that it contains called itself, over, and over, and over again.

```
class newText
{
    public String newtext
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.newtext; //Get newtext again, which gets it again, and again, etc
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.newtext = value; //Set newtext, which calls set again, and again...
        }
    }
}
```

When you get or set `newtext`, it will get or set itself over and over again, resulting in a recursive loop. This will never end and will lead to a `StackOverflowException`.

The proper way to use a [property](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property) is to have the public accessor (`NewText`) that will perform logic (in this case, just get and set) and return or set a value, in this case, the storage variable `newText`

Here is an example:

```
private string newText; //Storage Field

public string Newtext //Accessor
{
    get { return newText; }
    set { newText = value; }
}
```

C# 3.0 has [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), so this is not necessarily necessary (:P).

As an added note, you do not have to use the `String` class, `string` and `String` are the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074/1218281), but using `string` is usually the preferred method.