# Is string.IsNullOrEmpty same as String.IsNullOrEmpty?

Tags: c#

Look at the following code. Are they the same? Is there any difference? If yes what?

```
    string f = textBox5.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("string");
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("String");
    }
```

Edit: Is a null or empty `string` test exactly the same as null or empty `String` test?

Comment: Why are people voting to reopen this?  The duplicate answers the question exactly, or *all* uses of `string` and `String`, *which includes this type of usage*.

Comment: As per this [_this existing question_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string) `string` is merely an *alias* for `System.String` as is true for all of the other primitive types. 
Given this, both statements will call  the exact same method so no, there is no difference.

Comment: @FloodGravemind I *did* mark it as a duplicate.  See below, "marked as duplicate by Servy [...]".  I do have a problem with people inappropriately reopening a question that is correctly closed.  Why shouldn't I be?  Why should I ignore something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ByteBlast said - they are the same thing but string is a keyword (and alias) for String (which is a class).
but remember, if you are porting over apps to WinRT, then String does not work - only string.

Answer (score 2):

`string` is just an alias for `System.String`, just like `object` is an alias for `System.Object`, so in short, they refer to exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same.
`string` is just an alias to `System.String`.