# Difference between Boolean and bool in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Visual Studio is showing two things for boolean type like:

`Boolean` and `bool`

And for double type:

`Double` , `double`

Why so? Two are in different colors and will they both are same? What is the difference?

Comment: they are the same. only that `bool` is an alias of `Boolean`. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/491243)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. If you mouse over the lowercase one it shows that it is an alias to the uppercase version.

Note that by convention you should always use the lowercase version

Answer (score 2):

`bool` is an alias for `System.Boolean`, where as `double` is an alias for `System.Double` and `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`

They are all essentially the same.