# Convert a int to a textbox text?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, compiler-errors

I have this code in c#:

```
int i;
i += textBox1.Text;
textBox1.Text = i;
```

But it is giving me errors on both of those last codes. How do I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Why is this question getting down votes? It is a perfectly fine question. :'(

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between String and string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: You are getting downvotes most likely because you didn't state what your errors are and there are fundamental issues with the code.  Variable initialization mainly.  Note: I didn't downvote, just my observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying make a `String` an `Int` You have to `Convert` the `String` to an `Int`

Put this code in:

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

You can also `Parse` it, and do `TryParse`.

If you want to do this for something besides a int, you can change to whatever you want. For example:

```
Convert.ToDouble
```

Converts it to a `Double`, instead of a `Int`.

Comment: I think you mean `Convert.ToInt32`

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
i+= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

There are other functions in `Convert` class as well like `ToInt64`, `ToDouble` etc. Also you may want to use `TryParse` if you are not sure the text box always contains number:

```
var x = 0;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out x))
{
    i+=x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to use `+=` with an uninitialized variable,you will get a compiler error:

> The variable **i** might not be **initialized** before accessing.

So first you need to initialize your variable, simply assign it to **0** when you defining it:

```
int i = 0;
```

And then you are trying to add a string to an integer.C# is a strongly typed language.Therefore you can't assign an integer to a string directly.To do this first you should Convert your string to Integer, then append to your actual variable:

```
int i += Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Third line you are trying to assign an integer to a string.To do this you should convert back to your integer variable to string.You can use `.ToString` method or `Convert.ToString`

```
textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code

```
int i;
i += textBox1.Text;
textBox1.Text = i;
```

has some problems.

First, you'll get a compiler error (two, actually) due to the type mismatch. `i` is an `int`; `textBox`.Text`is a string. There is no implicit cast or conversion from`string`to`int` and so the compiler throws an error.

Second, having fixed the above issue, you'll get another compiler error due to `i` not being initialized. The C# specification required variable to be explicitly assigned a value prior to first use. Something like `i += j;` is shorthand for `i = i + j;`. And since you haven't assigned a value to `i`, the compiler throws an error.

You might note that the compiler errors you see

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

and

```
error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
```

are rather descriptive of the problem. The solution should be rather obvious on reading the compiler error messages. What you want to do is something like:

```
int value ;
bool parsed = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out value ) ;

if ( !parsed ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "you should have client-side validators on textBox1") ;

i += value ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a string to an `int` unless you parse it and it succeeds. You may also want to call `.ToString()` on `i` when assigning it to the textbox's text. Consider using `int.TryParse()`, by the way, or at least handle invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this one;

```
int xout;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out xout)){
 i += xout;
 textbox1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

the different between Convert.ToInt32 and int.TryParse:
if textbox have not integer string Convert.ToInt32 throw and exception but int.TryPary will not