# Adding up the numbers in a string in php

Tags: php, string, random, numbers

Adding a string with a variable *$a = 'ABC-01-222222';* with *$b = 1;* and it should give *$a = 'ABC-01-222223'*

Comment: Explode this string into 3 variables and process each individually. Then concatenate to display.

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you going to show us what you tried?

Comment: I know i did used String conversion to numbers http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion using the above link ...but i did failed in getting answer. so i didn't posted the code. I need a short methodology(i mean an small snippet method) that's it...i don't anybody to correct my code @oliakaoil

Comment: Do please remove the negative points in there ... i don't need you to correct my code

Comment: This site is for programming questions. it is not a "do my job for me", especially when you can't even be bothered to try doing this yourself, or show what you've tried. And note that I said "questions". You haven't asked one. You're basically just stating a demand, and expecting us to do it for you.

Comment: hey @MarcB am not asking for answers i clearly mentioned in my comments that i have the intention in methods only. I don't need your answer for the example i provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the value of `$a` into three parts. Then add `$b` to the third item of the array, and then re-join the parts using [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$a = 'ABC-01-222222';
$b = 1;

$parts = explode('-', $a);
$parts[2] += $b;

$a = implode('-', $parts);
echo $a;
```

Comment: It's impossible to know if this is actually what he needs, or whether or not your answer just happens to work for the specific example. You also shouldn't encourage these kinds of questions by answering them blindly.

Comment: Hey @oliakaoil if you don't want to answer, you just carry on your work don't interfere with others initiative

Comment: Hey @GeekManiax There's a reason this site allows downvoting and commenting without answers. We are both trying to make the site better by giving our opinion. Telling me "don't say anything if you don't have something nice to say" is *seriously* missing the point.

Comment: @oliakaoil OP will decide if this is what he needs. If not, I will ask him to improve his question and based on the new information I will either edit or delete my answer.

Comment: @GergoErdosi what I'm saying is you should have done that *first* before giving some canned answer that doesn't actually help the OP.

Comment: @oliakaoil see i didn't posting a unmeaningful question or something. Also this is not only for Correcting Coding Stuffs and helping someone who is really struggling with coding. This site is for way of improvising the development methods. Its upto you mark a downvote, if you feel it's wrong. But don't make a mess in a initiative. It doesn't improve a new comer

Comment: Also @oliakaoil see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string?rq=1 why this question is posted and its answered. They may see in the php documentation itself. but why they are posting is they need many answers to choose from & then they understand easy. So is it makes sense for you!!!!