# Boxing the string in c#

Tags: c#, boxing

Whenever I Search for Boxing in c#, I come across a cliche example like following:

```
string s = "something";
Object o = s;
```

This is very simple to understand that a value type is cast into a very generic reference type at run time. Well and good. I want to talk about little more specific kind of boxing:

```
int i= something;
String s2 = 2
```

- Hoping that this example qualifies for the definition of boxing, I would like to note that it is not limited to string to String. It also applies to int to Integer.
- If I am not wrong all primitive type are primitive representation of their corresponding reference type and they are something we can call "light weight wrappers"

  - Now my question is that is there ANY benefit of boxing primitive type to its corresponding reference type at run time at all?

Comment: That's not boxing at all. String is a reference type, only value types can be boxed. String already lives in heap.

Comment: do you know what the string keyword is alias for?...hint,it starts with capital S...

Comment: First of all: Java and C#, big difference. `string` is a reference type in both of them so there is no boxing. What C# has is called an alias.

Comment: `Integer` doesn’t exist in C#, and `System.Int32` is a value type, so no boxing.

Comment: Your question seems to be about Java. C# doesn’t have any primitive wrappers at all. Boxing would occur by placing a value type in an `object`.

Comment: `Object o = s` it's not boxing but rather upcasting since `object` is root for all type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxing is turning a value type into a reference type.  It puts an object (reference type) box around the value type.
Primitive types do not have corresponding reference types so your question about `boxing primitive type to its corresponding reference type at run time` is not valid.

`int` is a C# keyword which serves as an alias of the predefined .NET framework value type `System.Int32` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Example of boxing:

```
int i = 5;
object o = i;   //box the primitive type int in an object.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string s= something;
String s2 = 2
```

This is not boxing. String is a reference type and when it comes to C# then when you say String then it is a class and it has an alias name of string. Please refer this super question and answer given by Jon Skeet:- [What's the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string/215422#215422)

Also there is no Integer in C# rather there is [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) and [System.int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.int32.aspx) which is a vlaue type and you dont have boxing on values types.

And last but not the least *Java is not C#*

Comment: C# has boxing and unboxing, please see the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing