# safe cast unknown boxed or reference type to value type

Tags: c#, duck-typing

### Problem statement

I have an method argument of type `object` that can be a couple of different types, including boxed int, boxed string and a couple of different reference types.  I need to safely duck type the object before processing it.  This is no problem for reference types, I could use `is` or `as`, but how can I generalise it to safely duck type the boxed types as well?

### My attempt

Currently I'm trying to do this with reflection but would prefer to avoid that, I'm calling LogMemberTry from a breakpoint Action and it is not reliable.

```
public string LogMemberTry(object host, string[] options, string label = "")
{
    var result = "";
    var i = 0;

    if (host == null || host.GetType().IsValueType)
        return Pre(label) + (host?.ToString() ?? "null");

    foreach (var option in options) // return the first viable option
    {
        if((result = getValue2(host, option)?.ToString() ?? "null") != "null")
            break;
    }
    return Pre(label) + result;
}
```

and

```
using static System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

    private object getValue2 (object host, string member)
    {
        object retVal = null;
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = Public | NonPublic | Instance;
        var hostType = host.GetType();
        var members = hostType.GetMember(member, bindingFlags);

        while (members.Length == 0 && hostType != typeof(object))
        {
            hostType = hostType.BaseType ?? typeof(object);
            members = hostType.GetMember(member, bindingFlags);
        }

        if (members.Length == 0) return null;

        members = members.Where(
            m =>
                (m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                || (m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        ).ToArray();


        if (members.Length == 0) return null;

        switch (members[0].MemberType) // first field or property
        {
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                retVal = hostType.GetProperty(member, bindingFlags)
                    .GetValue(host);
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                retVal = hostType.GetField(member, bindingFlags)?
                    .GetValue(host);
                break;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why the "is" is to be avoided?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, I think maybe I've confused myself here. I'll go back to the drawing board and see what I can figure out... I can't debug this code while in use because it's called from a breakpoint action and there is a bunch of other stuff going on that obfuscates what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide an example of  "boxed string"?

Comment: Also `dynamic` is much easier way of duck typing - why can't you use that (which will do all that reflection code properly for you)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov boxed string is `object o = "my string";` and I also have to deal with `object I = 2;` for example. But, I was thinking that `is` was like `as` in that it would throw if testing for non-reference types, as pointed out by Mario, that's not true so I can use it. Regarding dynamic, the object I am receiving if from the WPF source code so I can't change the type.

Comment: I see - you have your own definition of "boxing"  unrelated to what is called "boxing of value types" in .Net. I still would recommend reading on dynamic as I think you have wrong idea about it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did some reading, I see what you mean... can receive it as dynamic and then use easy reflection.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, by the way, what is the proper definition of "boxing"? From what I can see, given `object o = 2; int i = 2; object boxedInt = i`, `o` and `boxedInt` are identical no?

Comment: What you've shown in comment is indeed boxing. But based on your post it is likely you define boxing as "assigning to object is boxing". Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230986/boxing-the-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @CoolBlue the "boxing" operation is somewhat the system applies to any "struct"-like object. You know, any "struct" is automatically copied from a location to another, that is the default behavior is NOT copy the reference as all the other objects. By the way, as soon you use an "universal" interface as "object" is, the system must provide some mechanism to pass the reference (=pointer, if you like). Thus, the "struct" is "boxed" as an ordinary reference object somewhere in the heap, then treated as an ordinary instance.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, my definition of boxing is the same as yours; the value type is already boxed before it is passed to my method. I'm not using the term to describe the casting to my method signature if that's what you mean. Anyway, regarding ducktyping with `dynamic`, this looks very promising!