# Custom ReSharper pattern - using String.SomeMethod instead of string.SomeMethod

Tags: c#, string, resharper

I know there is no different between `string` and `String` in C# (except for the `using System` that is added for `System.String`). Still, same like in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string/7077#7077), I'd prefer to use string with a lowercase `s` as type, and String with an uppercase `S` when I call a String.SomeMethod (for example `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`; `String.Format(...)` or `String.Empty`.

[I know I can add custom patterns in ReShaper using `Visual Studio RESHARPER menu` -> `Option` -> `Code Inspection` -> `Custom Patterns` -> `Add pattern`.](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern.html) I've added the following custom pattern:

- Search pattern: `string.$method$`
- Pattern severity: `Show as suggestion`
- Match similar constructs: `Unchecked`
- Search Description: `Check if string.SomeMethod is used instead of String.SomeMethod`
- Replace pattern: `String.$method$`
- Format after replace: `Checked`
- Shorten reference: `Unchecked`
- Replace Description: `Use String instead of string`

On a line like `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)` it does indeed give the suggestion and replaces it correctly to `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`. The problem however, is that it now also gives the suggestion when it's already correct or after I've replaced it. So is it possible to make the Search pattern case-sensitive? So it will only give the suggestion at `string.SomeMethod`, instead of also at `String.SomeMethod`?

EDIT: Also, is it possible to have an option to apply it to the entire project/solution, similar to the warning `Remove unused directives in file` -> `Remove unused directives in solution` (in v8.0 or higher)?

Comment: "There isn't a lot of differences between string and String in C#." - There is **NO difference**. `string` is an alias for `String`.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Yet you can have a preference of using one or the other and if you do, it would be wise to be consistent throughout your code base; so it's not an unreasonable question.

Comment: @decPL, I am not saying that it is a unreasonable question, I was just referring to the statement in question, *(which has now been edited out)*

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this behavior is because `string` and `String` are identical and ReSharper quite often performs type reductions behind the scenes. SSR is one such place where lots of generalizations and possible rearrangements take place. To cut the long story short, SSR is designed for syntactic changes, and what you are (effectively) doing is performing a purely symbolic change that doesn't actually change the code as far as anyone is concerned.