# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'String'

Tags: c#, types, compiler-errors

The following code fails to compile with the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'String'` in C#.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Hello".Append("Mark"));
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static String Append<String>(this String str, String app)
    {
        return str + " " + app;
    }
}
```

You can fix the compile error by removing the Type parameter from the extension method but I'm wondering why this fails to compile given that `typeof(string) == typeof(String)` evaluates to `true`.

The following also works just fine:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Hello".Append("Mark"));
}
public static class Ext
{
    public static string Append<String>(this String str, string app)
    {
        return str + " " + app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a type constraint `<String>` here?

Comment: I was writing a number of extension methods that used a T parameter, but this one only made sense for String so I replaced T with String and was surprised to receive the error. It certainly doesn't need to be there. The following code compiles and runs just fine:
    `void Main()
    {
            Console.Write("Hello".Append("Mark"));
    }
    public static class Ext
    {
        public static string Append<String>(this String str, string app)
        {
            return str + " " + app;
        }
    }`

Comment: There is no need to make extension methods generic since the first argument `this String str` already defines the target type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Append<String>` is not a type, it's the name of a type parameter. It's the same as using `T` except now you name it `String`.

Obviously this gives a problem because now you try to concatenate a generic type with name `String` to a `string` literal.

You can just omit this altogether:

```
public static String Append(this String str, String app)
{
    return str + " " + app;
}
```

The reason your second approach works is because you now use `string` which removes the ambiguity of the type parameter named `String`.

This means that your concatenation consists of the generic type named `String` which has the actual type `string`, a `string` literal and a variable of type `string`. This can compile again but it's ugly and you should never do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is, that you use a generic type argument `String` which is understooed by the compiler as "some type, but let us call it String" and not as the actual type `System.String`.

Furthermore, there is no need to make extension methods generic since the first argument `this String str` already defines the target type. Just remove the type parameter and you are good to go:

```
public static string Append(this string str, string app)
{
    return str + " " + app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees your declaration:

```
public static string Append<String>(this String str, string app)
```

And it then treats `String` as type parameter. So `str` is not (necessarily) of type `System.String`. It's of whatever your type parameter turns out to be. Second argument, namely `app` however is of type `System.String`, because you used lowercase [`string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string). In the body you have

```
return str + " " + app;
```

Which means "take `str` and add it to string `" "` and then to string `app`", but the compiler doesn't know how to add `str`, because it's of unknown type `String`.

It would be best to remove the type parameter altogether, because you don't use it anyway, but if you want it to stay you should change its name to `T` (that's the convention)

Answer (score -1):

I'think this solves your Problem with an correct extension method and also the usage of string.Format()

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello".Append("Mark"));
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static System.String Append(this System.String str, System.String app)
    {
        return System.String.Format("{0} {1}", str,app);
    }
}
```