# How to access the Body of a Post or Put in Asp.net WebAPI using Postman?

Tags: asp.net, .net, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have some simple code here is my Put handler .

**My problem is value is blank or my second write line doesn't work in either method. How come I am not accessing the post or puts body right?**

```
  // PUT api/activate/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Put !");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);


    }
```

heres my Post Handler code

```
 public void Post([FromBody]String value)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Post !");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);


        }
```

heres the error i get

> iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'null'',
>   Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync iisexpress.exe
>   Information: 0 :
>   Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=204
>   (NoContent) iisexpress.exe Information: 0 :
>   Operation=ActivateController.ExecuteAsync, Status=204 (NoContent)
>   iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=204 (NoContent),
>   Method=PUT, Url=http://localhost:53676/api/activate/3,
>   Message='Content-type='none', content-length=unknown' iisexpress.exe
>   Information: 0 : Operation=ActivateController.Dispose The program
>   '[14136] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

this is how I am sending the put or post using postman

[image]

I get a 204 when sending it but that seems ok because I am not returning anything.

**What I am trying to do is access value from my asp.net code. Ie the writeline for value wont print anything because I cant get the value from the body correctly.

In a rails I would say response.body to access this server side. How do I access the data I posted in my asp.net code??**

Comment: I do not see you returning any content from your Put and Post -

Comment: its void do i have to? my issue is not being able to get the data I posted or puted in my asp.net server side code

Comment: the 204 response that you are receiving is correct since your actions return void http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/09/28/ASPNET-Web-Api-Unwrapping-HTTP-Error-Results-and-Model-State-Dictionaries-Client-Side.aspx

Comment: I think I worded the question wrong. My issue is how do I access the value of the body in my asp.net code. I can't seem to print that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Request in an MVC app are routed using names.
If you have `http://localhost:53676/api/activate/?country=jordan`
The method `public void Post(string country)` would recieve that Post Value. 
Also use string Not String in methods, it is best practice even if they are the same in the end. See [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)