# How string is available without using system Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

Can anyone tell,I'm not using system namespace but string is available as  string hello = "Hello"; and does not throw any compile time error

but, if I write uppercase String it is not available.

```
sealed class SealedClass
{
    public void PrintSealed()
    {
        string hello = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Get an answer in this question: [What's the difference between String and string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string?rq=1)

Comment: That is clear, but I'm asking how I'm able to use string but not String without using System namespace.

Comment: @BhuwanPandey It is cleary written: *string is an alias in C# for System.String. So technically, there is no difference. It's like int vs. System.Int32.* *string* isn't an alias inside the namespace `System`. It is an alias stop.

Comment: Check [Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) to learn about these alias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the `using` keyword to use a "piece" of library. The `using` keyword is only to make it easier to reference types inside namespaces.

When you write

```
using System;

.... ...

String hello = "Hello";
```

the compiler replaces it with

```
System.String hello = "Hello";
```

But you could have written directly

```
System.String hello = "Hello";
```

without the `using System`. But it is a pain :-)

Then `string` is an alias to `System.String`, so when you write `string`, the C# compiler replaces it with `System.String` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)).

Note that to use a library you still have to reference it, but you don't reference it from the code, you reference it from the project, doing `Add Reference`. The `mscorlib` library (assembly) is automatically referenced (and you can't remove the reference)

This is a little different from Microsoft Visual C/C++, where often there is something like:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "somelibrary")
```

that is an instruction to the linker to include a `.lib` file (a library). In Visual C/C++ often you don't need to include explicitly a library, you can simply include its header that contains that command, and the library will be auto-magically linked by the linker.

Comment: u said:Then string is an alias to System.String, so when you write string, the C# compiler replaces it with System.String. can you please include the source where it is mentioned. thanks

Comment: @Alex Here there is the table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Comment: I've added an MSDN link which states that string is indeed an alias. Also, +1 from me!