# CSharp CMD Problems

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I'm new on c#. So i created simple cs file including code template. I removed using System line and tried to write my code using fully qualified name like System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
But when i tried to compile it on CMD i got this error message :

> Test.cs(4,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'String' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
code : 

    //using System;
namespace first{
    class Test{
        static void Main(String[] args){
            System.Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C#");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think youl will find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543664/how-string-is-available-without-using-system-namespace... so you need to write "System.String[]"

Comment: You caire about Console.WriteLine and forget (String[]..) , so you have also add system to String like (System.String[]