# Why are the aliases for string and object in lowercase?

Tags: c#, alias, naming, primitive-types, complextype

Here are a list of aliases in C# (compliments of [What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)):

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

I can see `bool` through `char` being lowercase aliases, because they are primitive types.

Why are object and string not capitalized, since they are complex types?  Is this an oversight by the developers, or is there a necessary reason for them to be lowercase?  Or is this an opinionated question?

You end up with things like `string.Format()` instead of `String.Format()`, which just look funky and make me think `string` is a variable.

Comment: to be more like C++? adopters could continue using C# as they were used to doing it in previous languages?

Comment: You *can* still write `String.Format()`, assuming you have a `using System;`.

Comment: Also C# drew a lot of conventions and approaches very similar to Java, which has a very similar structure.  It can be kind of confusing when dealing with boxing/unboxing, as sometimes people get the impression one is boxed and one is unboxed, but that is not the case.

Comment: it seems to me that this has been discussed in multiple different questions with *thousands* of votes;  not sure that another question on the same topic is going to create any further clarification.

Comment: @Claies : then just flag the post as duplicate, with a link to one of those thousands.

Comment: Well if they capitalized the keyword then it would conflict with the `String` class, so the class would need to be renamed (or all uses of it would require an `@`).

Comment: @Servy : I guess the point of the question is "why are there aliases for the 'basic types' when they bring nothing except they're lowercase ?"

Comment: @cosmo0 But that's *not* what the question is asking.

Comment: @Servy True. As an aside, why are you answering the question in a comment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, there are no "primitive types" and "complex types". There are [`class`es and `struct`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx), (reference types and value types, respectively) among others. Both can include methods (e.g. `char.IsDigit('a')`). So your objections aren't really valid. But there is still the question: why?

I'm not sure if there's a good source for this, but I think the lowercase aliases are done to match the [other C# keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), which are themselves modeled on C/C++ keywords.

Answer (score 11):

Because all [keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) (reserved identifiers) are lowercase.

Comment: While that might not be the "original" reason (maybe @EricLippert) sees/knows this, I think the "for consistency" argument is not the worst. (One might ask though: why are all keywords lowercase :-).

Comment: @Christian.K, because C# derives much of its syntax from Java which derived much of its syntax from C, both of which use lower case fro keywords.

Comment: @DavidArno: Thanks, but I knew. I was just trying to push the envelope for those that don't :-)

Comment: Going beyond this requires reading minds and mind-reading is frowned upon around here.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your last comment:

> You end up with things like `string.Format()` instead of `String.Format()`, which just look funky and make me think string is a variable.

With C# 6, this becomes a moot point as you can do:

```
using static System.String;

...
var x = Format(...);
```

Or going further, you can do away with `string.Format` altogether and use `$` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is simple. If you want to use it like a class use `String`, if you want  to use it like a keyword use `string`. Developers wanted to make us feel like we are using a primitive type. Because in C# nothing is primitive.