# Get the method name that was passed through a lambda expression?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates, pinvoke

Is it possible to retrieve via **Reflection** the real method name that was passed through a lambda expression?

I would like to platform invoke some functions with a better error-handling, then to avoid repeating tons of `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` conditionals, I thinked in create a generic method to automate that, where I pass a reference object and a lambda expression:

```
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Private Shared Sub SafePInvoke(Of T)(ByRef resultVar As T, ByVal [function] As Func(Of T))

    resultVar = [function].Invoke

    Dim lastError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error

    If lastError <> 0 Then
        Throw New Win32Exception([error]:=lastError, message:=String.Format("Function '{0}' thrown an unhandled Win32 exception with error code '{1}'.",
                                                                            [function].Method.Name, CStr(lastError)))
    End If

End Sub
```

Then, I can do this to simplify error-handlings:

```
Dim length As Integer
SafePInvoke(length, Function() NativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(hWnd))
```

I don't know if it can be improved more, it would be great to know it.

Well, now, and just for aesthetical things, If the function gets a win32 error I throw an exception and in the exception message I would like to show the real method name, in this case `GetWindowTextLength` instead of the "anonymous" lambda name.

This is possibly?.

Comment: You may not like the result, you could resort to an Expression Tree. The body however would be `GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)` you probably dont want the param.

Comment: from the expression body I think it could be possible to cast it to `MethodCallExpression` and take it's `Method` property (of type MethodInfo which have a Name property). Using an expression also mean you'll have to compile it inside your method to invoke it.

Comment: If for result we are talking about the syntax that takes the parameter, then actually I don't like the current syntax that I have to write (the "Function()" keyword of the lambda expression syntax). An expression tree will increment and/or will make complex the amount of writting in the parameter?, first time I hear about an expression tree (I'm already looking in MSDN)

Comment: its not* that* bad: `Sub SafePInvoke(Of T)(ByRef resultVar As T, expr As Expression(Of Func(Of T)))`  but it is not what you asked for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do this.  It would be simpler to pass a string var representing the error message you want to display or a portion thereof (like the function name).

The "simplest" way would be to use an [Expression Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).  For this, you would need to change the signature of `SafePInvoke` to accept an `Expression`.

With that you could compile the expression, and invoke it to execute the PInvoke.  If there is an error, work the expression tree to get the name:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
...
Private Shared Sub SafePInvoke(Of T)(ByRef result As T, expr As Expression(Of Func(Of T)))
    ' compile the function and invoke it
    Dim result = expr.Compile.Invoke()

    Dim lastError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error

    If lastError <> 0 Then
        ' this is easy, but it is the full signature w/ params
        'Dim name = expr.Body.ToString

        ' ToDo: add try Catch
        Dim MethName = CType(expr.Body, MethodCallExpression).Method.Name

        Dim errMsg = MethName & " failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Casting it to get the name was Sehnsucht's idea, I gave up for the time being.

Comment: I second the "would not do this part" ; you want a name simply ask for one (possibly a clearer than the real method name). Also with VB14 addition you'll have the `NameOf` operator which can reduce the "magic string effect" : `SafePInvoke(length, Function() NativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(hWnd), NameOf(NativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength))` Sure it's some "duplicate code" but at least renaming will work with that

Comment: @Plutonix thanks again, just could you explain why you will not do this? it is only because for aesthethical things you will preffer to pass a string, or is because any problem about performance when using an expression?.

Comment: Its convoluted and I dont like the idea of expr -> lambda -> Pinvoke; too indirect for me.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, give him an upvote on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30713133/1070452) get him points and a bronze badge

Comment: (done) maybe now with the `MethodCallExpression` object I can do something with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878232/check-at-run-time-whether-a-p-invoke-function-has-the-dllimportattribute-setlast both take a look please, I'm analyzing the entire class `MethodCallExpression`, especially the attribute properties, but it has a lot of properties and members to learn its purpose.

Comment: You should be able to get that from the Type using reflection, the trick there is to get the Type of a lambda passed as an expression.  It would be simpler to make the PInvokes private with a dedicated Shared wrapper to do whatever you want pass whatever you want etc.  Since **many** Pinvokes return a code indicating fail/succeed that makes MUCH more sense.