# Console.ReadKey causing error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

So I have a script to take a word that has been typed and reverse it to tell the person if it is a palindrome or not everything seem to be fine besides a error from this line of code. any idea why as i have been sitting here getting frustrated at it. Let me know if you need more of the code.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo Keyinfo = Console.readkey();
```

Also have complication of only being able to type one letter instead of writing a word and pressing enter any advice?

Comment: So what *is* the error? Never, ever post a question saying you've got an error without specifying what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is case-sensitive.

```
Console.readkey();
```

should be

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This method, by definition, reads **a** key. If you want to read more than **one** character (the entire line, for example), you should be using [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), which reads all characters from the input until it reaches a new line.

Since `ReadLine` and `ReadKey` return different types, you'll also need to change your variable type (and probably the name as well since it's not keyinfo anymore!)

```cs
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Looking at the documentation page of `Console.ReadLine`, you might notice `String` is used in some places and `string` in others. Essentially nothing - `string` is a C# alias for the .NET framework type named `String`. More about that in this StackOverflow question: [What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: oh wow i feel stupid haha cheers

Comment: No problem! In the future, you might want to google the method name and find the MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) page for the method you want. For example, if you want to find all methods (functions) available in the Console class, look at [its MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: so if i were to change me Console.ReadKey() to ReadLine do i have to change my ConsoleReadKey to ConsoleReadLine?

Comment: @plan122 Good question! I can definitely see why it would seem that way. If you open the link I provided in my answer, it will open the documentation page for `Console.ReadLine()`. From there, you can see what type it returns: http://i.imgur.com/8XoQolW.png

Comment: thanks for looking out the new guy :)

Comment: @plan122 We've all been there at some point! If you have any questions related to C# or programming in general which you don't think belong on StackOverflow, you can find my Skype username on [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr?tab=profile)!