# Why in Visual Studio 2015 string.IsNullOrEmpty is better than String.IsNullOrEmpty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have been writing String.IsNullOrEmpty for years, and in Visual Studio 2015, the IDE suggests to refactor it into string.IsNullEmpty, Why? what would you do?

I well understand what behind String and string, however, I just wonder why VS 2015 could give me a hint I don't need.

Comment: `String` and `string` are synonyms, so I don't know why it tells you that, since they really point to the same type, one can't be better than the other. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's due to a "Code Style" option, under:

> Tools / Options / Text Editor / C# / Code Style

Uncheck the following option, and it should stop warning you.

[image]

If you find the styles useful, in that they force a certain uniformity on your code that you like to be warned about, then leave it checked. Personally, I'd just uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks. I uncheck it and feel happy now. :)

Answer (score 2):

> The IDE suggests to refactor it into string.IsNullEmpty, Why?

Actually there is no difference between `String` and `string` since both are same and `string` is just an alias. If VS still complaining about re-factoring it then probably because of some `FxCop` code analysis rules. You may want to verify the same.

In one of my work experience, they had a `FxCop` custom rule setup to use the actual Type name instead of alias like use `String` instead of `string` (OR) `Int32` instead of `int`.