# Why does Resharper 9 suggest to simplify String to string?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

Why does Resharper 9 suggest to use `string` instead of `String`, when referring to a class, like `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `String.Format()`, while Resharper 8 didn't ?

Based on a SO post, it should not.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077/3410616

Comment: If Jon Skeet mentions `Personally I tend to use string everywhere... – Jon Skeet Feb 12 '12 at 16:34`, then the universe bends to match this. Resharper is no exception.

Comment: Because that's a new diagnostic they introduced in that version. You can reconfigure that if it bothers you.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Can you source it ?

Comment: @Stralos nope, I just noticed it at some point too. JetBrains don't give such a detailed changelog AFAIK - they only list major changes between versions, and this one is a minor one.

Comment: Not sure it is related to resharper. I do not have resharper and it suggest the same for me. I am using VS2015 Pro.

Comment: @JimG. Your edit looks like an overall improvement, but removing the [resharper] tag while leaving in [resharper-9.0] is not appropriate. If it's not related to Resharper, then both tags should go. If it is related to Resharper, then [resharper] should stay. Optionally, [resharper-9.0] can go, but that's iffy. Discussion on that last part [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258713/what-to-do-about-teamcity-and-resharper).

Comment: This seems to show up in corefx guidelines https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the latest trend and also suggested under Roslyn:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/391