# Configure cultureInfo for Specflow

Tags: parsing, datetime, specflow

I have two machines with different cultures where the format `mm/dd/yyyy` is successfully parsed by Specflow (it's a step argument) in one but fails in the other.

I want my tests to be culture independent. So how to configure Specflow to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for parsing dates ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as nobody answered this. My solution for the problem was to edit the `App.config` file and add `<bindingCulture name="en-US" />` in the `<specflow>` config section.

This forces Specflow, on both machines, to correctly parse `MM/dd/yyyy` date format.

Comment: Thank you for coming back with the answer. Niche knowledge like this can be very valuable and I wish SO found a way how this can be rewarded more than just assigning it a few reputation points, [while programming-101 questions are getting upvoted to the outer atmosphere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string).

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a .NET Core answer, you need to add a `specflow.json` file, set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`, to your project.

```json
{
  "bindingCulture": "en-US"
}
```