# Why I don't need "using System" for C# data type aliases but need them for .NET types?

Tags: c#

Say I have a C# application without `using System` at the top. This will work:

```
string a;
```

but this won't:

```
String a;
```

Why does the first code work, although C# type keywords like `string` in the background map to `System.String` (which is not included in this sample code)? Don't they need `using System` to function?

Comment: `Don't they need using System to function?` - evidently not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: @Jamiec the first code works without "using System".

Comment: @daremkd Yes because `string a;` is equal to `System.String a;` which _already_ has the `System` part in it. It does not _need_ to specify the namespace part as additional. But when you write `String a;`, you _need_ to specify your namespace part as `using System;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `string` is an alias for `System.String`. *Just* `String` will not work because you will either need to specify `System.String` or include the `System` namespace like `using System;`.