# how can i split email id and display the text before @ in another textbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is a web application i have login it some fields like name,email id,login name like that but i need to split the email id @ before text it will display automatically in login name text box. when i entered email id  split and display another name another text box like this:

i want to display like this

> ```
> eamil id: xyz@gmail.com
> login name: xyz
> ```

i tried this code but not working:

```
String str= txtemailid.Text;
String[] name=str.split('@');
txtloginname.Text=name[0].Tostring();
```

can any one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string email = "xyz@gmail.com";
var name = email.Split('@')[0];
```

This works, but split is called with capital S. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: where should i take it in the text box event  in that email id text box event or login name text box event. could you please tell me which event i should take

Comment: If this is a web application, then you're basically left with 2 options, you can either do this in JavaScript and react to some changed() event, or you can do it when you submit the form, and check it with C# as in the example given above. This is, however a completely different question than the original one. If you're happy with the answer, please click on the checkmark :)

Comment: Great Suggestion : " please click on the checkmark :" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Comment: Thank you very much it help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qw6D3); It is better to check for the array Length after split since there may be a chance for entering wrong input, that may lead to exception in case of invalid input;

```
string str= "xyz@gmail.com";
string[] name=str.Split('@');
if (name.Length > 1)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("login name:{0}", name[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("login Domain:{0}", name[1]);  
 }
```

I thing You have not compile your code; since it having lots of errors;

`split()` will be [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) `S` is capital;
`Tostring()` will be `ToString()` here also `S` is capital; Here `.ToString()` is  not necessary since `name` is a string array. And one more Thing in C# [String and string are Different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string); so use `string` to declare variables;

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = "xyz@gmail.com";
var name = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf('@'));
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Simply without index of array.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change to capital "S" in two words (Split and ToString). If you do it, your code will work:

```
String str = txtemailid.Text;
String[] name = str.Split('@');
txtloginname.Text = name[0].ToString();
```