# Saving the string after using split [Gone WRONG]

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
char[] delimiterChars = {'-'};
string text = "123-45-6789"
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
foreach (string s in words)
{
  pdfFormFields.SetField("PutItHere: ", s);
}//foreach


Result: 
PutItHere: 6789
```

I want it to be like "123456789" , I dont know how to manipulate and put it like that. Pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should have used `Replace` instead

```
string text = "123-45-6789";
text = text.Replace("-", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Suggestion: for readability a lot of developers prefer `string.Empty` versus `""`.to make reading code look more *fluent*. ;)

Comment: should be `string` not `String`

Comment: How can I mark this as answer? Thanks a lot @MohitShrivastava

Comment: @MohitShrivastava no, `string` is nothing more than an alias of `String`, and the alias should be used.

Comment: @Phill I do agree with you. What I meant to say has been explained in detail here on [difference between String and string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7077/3796048).

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you want to use Split()?

If you have to use Split and put into a loop, you have to create a variable and concat each splitted string as the end result.

Also, `pdfFormFields.SetField()` need to put outside the loop. Otherwise the result will be replaced in each loop.

```
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (string s in words)
{
  result += s;
}//foreach
pdfFormFields.SetField("PutItHere: ", result);
```