# Why is "1.0" < "-1.0" < "1.1"?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider this code fragment:

```
var sorted = new[] { "-1.0", "0.0", "1.0", "1.1", "2.0" }
    .OrderBy (s => s)
    .ToArray ();
Console.WriteLine (string.Join (", ", sorted));
```

On my system this prints

```
0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.1, 2.0
```

Given that the Ascii code of `-` is lesser than the numbers' ascii codes I expected `-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0`.

It definitely confuses me why `-1.0` is *between* `1.0` and `1.1`. Those two start with the same char, so anything between them should start with a `1`, too.

I vaguely suspect a culture or locale setting to affect this, but mine (mixture of some German and a lot of English) should probably be no different from English or Invariant in the above case.

Comment: You can find the answer yourself by calling the comparer method directly (i.e. the default comparer for `string`). Have you bothered to investigate this in _any_ way? What have you done so far? Your question seems fairly lazy to me. Suspicions are no match for actually digging in and looking at what's going on.

Comment: Maybe [the documentation for `OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) can help?

Comment: All of this is explained in the documentation. Look at what method gets called to do the ordering (`CompareTo`) and look at the remarks stated. Surely that should be the first course of action rather than asking on SO.

Comment: @PeterDuniho if everyone was going to dig through the documentation or the code that causes unusual behaviour, this site would have a lot less traffic.

Comment: @MrPaulch: _"this site would have a lot less traffic"_ -- Maybe, but so what? Traffic for traffic's sake is pointless. And frankly, Stack Overflow has way too much low-quality traffic, which makes it that much harder to search for and find answers, as well as to find the questions worth answering.

Comment: This oughta be a meta discussion. But consider the [most highly voted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c) under the c# tag. A simple google search would lead to the documentation and the answer to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per MSDN Docs [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190416(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Notes to Callers: Character sets include ignorable characters. The
>   Compare(String, Int32, String, Int32, Int32, CultureInfo, CompareOptions)
>   method does not consider these characters when it performs a
>   linguistic or culture-sensitive comparison. To recognize ignorable
>   characters in your comparison, supply a value of
>   CompareOptions.Ordinal or CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase for the
>   options parameter.

If you add `StringComparer.Ordinal` it will work as expected.

```
        var sorted = new[] { "-1.0", "0.0", "1.0", "1.1", "2.0" }
            .OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.Ordinal)
            .ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sorted));
```

So as you can see the `-` will be completely ignored, meaning that `"-1.0"` and `"1.0"` are the same

Also as per [MSDN CompareOptions Enumeration Remakrs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The .NET Framework uses three distinct ways of sorting: word sort,
>   string sort, and ordinal sort. Word sort performs a culture-sensitive
>   comparison of strings. Certain nonalphanumeric characters might have
>   special weights assigned to them. For example, the hyphen ("-") might
>   have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op"
>   appear next to each other in a sorted list. String sort is similar to
>   word sort, except that there are no special cases. Therefore, all
>   nonalphanumeric symbols come before all alphanumeric characters.
>   Ordinal sort compares strings based on the Unicode values of each
>   element of the string.

Comment: Additional reading where a hyphen explicitly gets called out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `For example, if the following code is run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent.`

Was changed in Framework 4? I could not find a page documenting this.

Comment: Take a look at the following  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx