# Table Difference in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

In Excel, how can I get the difference between 2 tables?

I have 2 tables: A and B.
B is a subset of A. In other words, all rows/records of B are included in A, but not vice versa.

I would like to get
A - B
i.e. I want an output which gives me only the records which are in A but not in B.

Also, more generally, if B were not a subset, how would I get
A∪B - A∩B?

Comment: You could compare them with `IF` statements.  That's all I can give you with how much information you've provided.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks! But I am not sure I understand, how exactly an IF statement would be useful here. At the moment, I have the 2 "tables" in different files/workbooks. But I could easily get them into the same workbook as different worksheets, or even in the same sheet as different ranges...

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't see how this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c?rq=1

Comment: You could add a helper column in Table A using `=MATCH` to check if it is also in Table B and then filter on that helper column.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ I did end up using this rather mechanical way...`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$19902,0)),"Unique","Duplicate")`, then filtering and copy pasting....the tables weren't big....about 20k rows, so it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `VLOOKUP` to achieve this if this is going to be made only for once for a dataset. Just write a `VLOOKUP` fomula on the big table, the rows that are not in the small table will return `#N/A` error. When we filter out that error rows, we will have the minus'd rows left behind.

On the other hand this is also achievable using Power Query which is a cleaner way IMHO. For Excel 2010 you should download and install it. For the newer versions Power Query is included in Excel natively.

I am able to explain the process for Office 365 since I have that version; for previous versions slight changes may apply.

- First get your tables into Power Query using **Data** / **From Table/Range** menu.
- When you have your both tables to Power Query, right click on a blank space at the **Queries** pane at the left and go to **New Query / Combine / Merge Queries as New** menu:

[image]

- In this screen, select your tables (select the larger table in the first place), CTRL select the table fields to be minus'd and select **Left Anti** in the bottom combo. When you OK this you will have a minus'd new table.

[image]
 * Select **Close & Load** in the **Home** menu and your new table will be available in a new sheet in Excel.
 * When there is a change made in the original sheets, just press **Data / Refresh** in Excel and your generated table will be refreshed accordingly.