# C# System Namespace - why do I need to import it?

Tags: c#

In C# if I use a type alias like `string` instead of (`System.String`) then I do not need to add a `using System;` directive - it compiles just fine.

However, if I change the type from the alias to the aliased Type explicitly - `System.String` - then it will not compile without the `using` directive. This seems to be true of all primitive Types (`int`/`Int32`, `bool`/`Boolean`) etc.

Why does the compiler import `System` for me when using an alias but not when using the actual type name?

Comment: Most likely because they are aliases and reserved words and the clr understands what they are. also because someone made the decisions for that to be the case.

Comment: question goes to microsoft, this is how they have developed their framework. may be you can just have look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c/48120399 , it has many discussion on the same (mainly the string and System.String)

Comment: The compiler doesn't "import" `System` when you use an alias. It's exactly like if you had written `System.String` where you wrote `string` (which despite what you say at the start of your second paragraph, does compile without `using`). It's `String` without `System.` at the start that doesn't compile.

Comment: I had figured it dealt with native types vs boxed types. System.String is a class or struct with optimization attributes helping the compiler optimize the overhead away? Where string is part of the language definition. That is similar to how Java works. Boxing and a unboxing. But I don’t think Java optimizes/inlines them to be the same. .net core would help you see if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aliases are more "as if" at the top of every file, the compiler was inserting

```
using string = System.String;
using int = System.Int32;
using decimal = System.Decimal;
```

Etc.

I don't believe that's how the compiler actually implements<sup>1</sup> the built-in aliases, but that's the overall effect. When you use [using alias directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), you don't also need to have a `using` directive for their enclosing namespace, and it doesn't have the effect of also pulling it's enclosing namespace into scope.

---

<sup>1</sup>My search-foo in the Roslyn github repository is letting me down.

Comment: This makes perfect sense - it is not importing the namespace, it is aliasing the fully-qualified type name. Gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

There is practically no difference between both `string` and `System.String` but still `String`  the C# keyword string maps to the .NET type `System.String` - it is an alias that keeps to the naming conventions of the language.

Also `string` is a keyword (an alias in this case) whereas `String` is a type.

Note : If you use Visual Studio 2015 or + and try to use `String` the program suggests you to "simplify your code", carrying it to `string`

So you can avoid the System.String and go with string no problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import the namespace if you are not using the full, qualified name of the type:

```
namespace Test {
  class Cxx {
     public System.String _exampleField; 
  }
}
```

vs:

```
using System;

namespace Test {
  class Cxx {
     public String _exampleField; 
  }
}
```

You can import a single type from a namespace using an alias.

The built-in aliases work in a similar way to the ones you write;
if instead of the built-in alias `string` you had your own, they you would not need to import the whole System namespace:

```
using mystring = System.String;

namespace Test {
  class Cxx {
     public mystring _exampleField; 
  }
}
```

If the only types from the System namespace you use are the ones which have aliases, you don't need the import.

```
namespace Test {
  class Cxx {
     public string _exampleField; 
  }
}
```