# using System; to allow a method to return String? Random.Range cannot be use CS0104 [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Few question

1. Is it require to place using System; on top of script in order to
   create a method that return string as outcome?
2. Will using System stop Random.Range (0,2) from working?
3. How to avoid CS0104 or in this case randomly return a String value
   in method?

Below are really simple script i am working on, suddenly i cannot use Random.Range CS0104 ,

"Random" is an ambiguous reference between "UnityEngine.Random" and "System.Random".

As you can see i am trying to create a method that random return ABC or AAA randomly

Please kindly advise a fix , thanks in advance!

```
 using System; 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GSC : MonoBehaviour

    void Start()
    {
        
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }

  public String StoreNameRoller() 
    {
        int abc = Random.Range(0, 2);
        if ( abc == 1)
        {
            return "ABC";
        }
        else
        {
            return "AAA";
        }
    }
```

Fix to CS0104 That related to using system in unity
I do try according to suggestion, but then it saids System.Random.Range not exist blahblahblah

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c...

Comment: Did you try fully qualifying the namespace of `Random`? i.e. `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2)`. `System` has a class named `Random`, and so does `UnityEngine`. Having a `using` for both `System` and `UnityEngine` means it can't figure out which version of the `Random` class you're referring to.

Comment: @Alexei and Daniel thanks for the help, i don't even notice i use upper case lmao, guess thats why u don't code 2 Am in the morning,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using;

```
int abc = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2);
```

Or use `string` instead of `String` and delete;

```
using System;
```

`System` and `UnityEngine` libraries both have `Random` function. When both of them are imported compiler cannot understand which `Random` you're trying to use.

If you want to use `String` and `Random` just specify which random you're going to use.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer. And, just to add, if they wish to keep the System namespace, then they could always use the System's Random function. ---- E.g. for a random number between 0 and 100, they can use:  Random rnd = new Random(); int randomNum = rnd.Next(0, 100);

Comment: That's right. Also you can specify that Random function will always be using from `that`library in this context. E.g. `using Random = UnityEngine.Random;` means Random functions in this context belong to UnityEngine.Random, or `using Random = System.Random;`.